# Reason for correctness of multiple word orders in relative clauses

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clause

In the two examples below both ways of ordering the words seem to be correct. The sense is also maintained. I can't find the corresponding rules to understand how that is possible. Why exactly is this flexible syntax allowed?

**1.**

> Sprachen, in denen die Bedeutungskonturen der Wörter und Sätze nicht
> **verwischt werden** von - fruchtbaren oder unfruchtbaren - Nebulositäten des neueren Subjektivismus [...]

Or:

> Sprachen, in denen die Bedeutungskonturen der Wörter und Sätze nicht
> von - fruchtbaren oder unfruchtbaren - Nebulositäten des neueren Subjektivismus **verwischt werden** [...]

**2.**

> Eine Auskunft, die in auffälligem Kontrast **steht** zu dem
> Bescheidenheitsgestus des Unwissenden [...]

Or:

> Eine Auskunft, die in auffälligem Kontrast zu dem
> Bescheidenheitsgestus des Unwissenden **steht** [...]

Comment: Yes, the sentences are explained with the "Präpositionalgruppen" from the "Nachfeld". Thats what I was looking for, thanks.